# Linux: how to test if in maintenance mode?

Tags: bash, runlevel

I want to run some things differently if I have booted into single-user/maintenance mode.

I want to know how I can test in my `.bashrc` file. In particular, I would like to start `tmux` only in that mode.

Answer (score 1):

Where this info is found possibly varies by distro.  Here's a couple of commands that may be helpful:

In Ubuntu Recovery mode (I assume this is single-user), `who -r` outputs nothing, and `runlevel` outputs an error `runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory`

In Ubuntu normal boot mode (multi-user), you get the following output:

```
$ who -r
         run-level 2  2015-06-27 21:41
$ runlevel
N 2
$
```

Here `runlevel` outputs the previous run level ("N") and the current run level ("2").

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`systemd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd) based systems really don't have runlevels or anything like that, what services are active can be quite more fine grained. At least Fedora retains `runlevel(8)` and organizes running services into runlevels à la SysV, but that isn't mandatory.